# SharePoint Framework: How to detect when Knockout ViewModel has been created?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, knockoutjs

In a SharePoint Framework webpart based on knockout the knockout component and its view model are created asynchronously as they are registered like this:

```
  private _registerComponent(tagName: string): void {
    ko.components.register(
      tagName,
      {
        viewModel: MyViewModel,
        template: require('./mytemplate.html'),
        synchronous: false
      }
    );
  }
```

I need to know when this process is finished, e.g. when the ViewModel ist ready.

How can I detect when the ViewModel is ready? Some method to override? Some knockout magic?

Background: I need to send web part properties to my view model using the built-in "_shouter" object, but need to wait for the view model to be created to make sure it is listening for the messages.